# Can't get correct path location to a folder in project

Tags: c#, directory

I created a folder inside my project like this:

[image]

And the path I get in windows explorer is

```
D:\Projekti\SeleniumTesting\SeleniumTesting\ErrorScreenshots
```

I need to get this path in my code, however I don't want to hard-code it so I tried to get the relative path like this:

```
string finalpath = Path.Combine(Path.GetDirectoryName(Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().Location), @"ErrorScreenshots\" + screenshotName);
        string localpath = new Uri(finalpath).LocalPath;
```

However, the path I get while debugging looks like this:

```
D:\\Projekti\\SeleniumTesting\\SeleniumTesting\\bin\\Debug\\ErrorScreenshots\\Screenshot_13112018
```

Any ideas on how could I get the "**D:\Projekti\SeleniumTesting\SeleniumTesting\ErrorScreenshots**" path?

Comment: If the path will always be two directory levels up from the executing assembly then you can use "..\..\" in your `Path.Combine` argument list.  Otherwise I would probably recommend storing the path in a config value for the application so you can easily change it any time you need to change the path (such as in a different executing environment).

Comment: Why do you need the path relative? Do you want to distribute the ErrorScreenshots folder together with your program and execute it on different computers? (Since it is only an empty folder, why add it to the project? You could just let your program create this folder if it is not found at the expected/desired location.)

Comment: @elgonzo This is a project with Selenium tests so the project will in future automatically run tests from a server, so the project will be ran on a server PC.

Comment: Okay, i understand. Then make the folder configurable, as David mentioned. Having a hardcoded path (no matter whether it is relative or absolute path) has the potential of making things more complicated with regard to server setup...

Comment: Will do, thank you both.